# I want to show the result of Math.round(score * 0.10), but what is shown is the result of the result

Tags: javascript, math

I have the following javascript code:

```
score -= Math.round(score * 0.10);
$('.sc').text(score);
$('.score').text('-' + Math.round(score * 0.10));
```

What does it do? Well lets say I have a div with class sc with score = 456 and I want 10% deducted from this without having decimals.

I use this:
`score -= Math.round(score * 0.10);` results in 456 - 46 = 410
`$('.sc').text(score);` makes the div sc show: 410

SO far so good, but I have another div with class: score. In this div I want to show the 46. I thought using `$('.score').text('-' + Math.round(score * 0.10));` would show it, but this results in 10% of the 410 and not the 456

So how can I show the 46 as result in the div: .score?

Kind regards,

Maurice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the deduction, rather than calculating it multiple times.

```
var penalty = -Math.round(score * 0.10); 
score += penalty 
$('.sc').text(score);
$('.score').text(penalty);
```

Comment: I think you mean `score += penalty;` since penalty is negative.

Comment: Ahh same as @el_bob, using a var is better indeed

Answer (score 1):

not sure why you don't just use a new variable and do it that way

```
var newScore = Math.round(score *= .9);
$('.sc').text(newScore);
$('.score').text('-' + (score - newScore));
```

where `score *= .9` gives you 90% of score (which is 10% off) and then you can just subtract from the original number.

to answer your question "why", when you do math on score a second time, you're doing it on the newest value, not the original.

Comment: Be aware of the difference between 'Math.round(score * 0.9)' and 'score - Math.round(score * 0.1)'. They are not always the same.

Answer (score 0):

You set score to the rounded result. Then you round it again.

Answer (score 0):

No need to subtract and all that:

```
$('.sc').text(Math.round(score*0.9));
$('.score').text("-" + Math.round(score*0.1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.sc').text(Math.round(score * .9));
$('.score').text('-' + Math.round(score * .1));
```